# Функция завершается не дойдя до return с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, олимпиада

вот код программы, из книги олимпиадное программирование. Он должен решать задачу о количестве способов разместить n ферзей на доске n*n чтобы они не били друг друга (перебор с возвратом)
суть в том что код ничего не выводит хотя должен вывести ans;
код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int n = 4;
int col[n]; int diag1[n]; int diag2[n];
int ans = 0;

void search(int y) {
    if (y == n) {
        ans++;
        cout << ans<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        if (col[x] || diag1[x + y] || diag2[x - y + n - 1])continue;
        col[x] = diag1[x + y] = diag2[x - y + n - 1] = 1;
        search(y + 1);
        col[x] = diag1[x + y] = diag2[x - y + n - 1] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {



    search(0);


    return 0;
}
```

Книга https://books.google.by/books/about/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC.html?id=34KzDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=twopage&q&f=false
cтраница 33-35

Comment: опишите проблему - из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно. Напишите: напишите что вы ожидаете и что по итогу имеете и почему то, что имеете - неправильное поведение

Comment: вроде все нормально описал

Comment: ну хорошо, давайте посмотрим задачу: о количестве способов разместить n ферзей на доске - вы вызываете вашу функцию с параметром 0 ферзей. А теперь подумайте немного: а какой количество способом разместить 0 ферзей на доске?

Comment: y это не кол-во ферзей, автор книги использует его просто как счетчик. Колво ферзей равно n

Comment: тобишь мы еще и книгу должны прочесть чтобы понять что же вы передаете в функцию?

Comment: y количество уже размещенных ферзей

Comment: ну а вообще какой вывод вы хотите, если единственная функция вывода вызывается только если количество уже размещенных ферзей равно общему количеству ферзей?

Comment: ну вывод по любому должен быть тк. именно там находиться return. Но ничего не выводит

Comment: последнее число в выводе должно быть ответом

Comment: Он у вас просто не доходит до `y==n`; https://ideone.com/rBwkP9 Почему именно - надо разбираться, но что-то сам принцип мне не нравится...

Comment: но как не доходит, там единственный return стоит

Comment: Не единственный - еще один после цикла, неявный...

Comment: спасибо, мне просто размера массивов не хватало для диагоналей, а разве continue может выкинуть из функции?

Comment: Скажите, что будет, когда закончится цикл `for(int x` - куда будет передано управление? Ну вот закончился цикл, `x==n` - что будет дальше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>В книге</s> у вас даны слишком мелкие массивы для диагоналей. Надо

```
int diag1[2*n-1]; int diag2[2*n-1];
```

(ну сами посчитайте число диагоналей). Вот они у вас и перезаписываются...

Ну, и выводить `ans` нужно не в `search`, а по окончании.

Вот работающая программа - https://ideone.com/J47BYq

P.S. Скачал книгу - с нее обвинение снимается, там размер `diag` не указан, это уже чисто ваша вина...

Comment: спасибо, сам чето не вьехал

Comment: На самом деле, `2*n-1`, полупериметр квадрата)

Comment: @vp_arth А, ну да... Ну, тут выделить больше - не страшно, лишь бы не меньше :)